# How long will a sauce last for when placed in a refrigerator and in a freezers?

Tags: food-safety

How long will a sauce last for when placed on freezer and in a refrigerator?

Comment: It depend on the sauce; what kind of sauce are you talking about?

Answer (score 1):

If it's sugary, or contains enough protein, a -20°C freezer won't stop problems. Sugar [epimerization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epimer), taste change, happens down to -70°C. You find those units in labs, not homes. Generally a freezer is good against bacterial and fungal growth. But you'll still have freezer burn after a year or so.Even with freezer bags. Actual containers work better, as 5-8mil plastic is fairly water permeable.